# how access function in try block of external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have external js file having following script:

```
try {
callback({x: 'abc', y: 'cde' });
}
catch(e) {
}
```

I have inject this script dynamically using following method:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://example.com/external.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

I m able to inject the script but I m not able to access the values passed in the callback() of external js.

I have some limitations as well:

1. The external js file cannot be modified.
2. This needs to be done in javascript only. I cannot use jQuery for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: load the external js.

Comment: so you should have a method in your code that is `function callback() { console.log(arguments); }` which should be defined before you add the script. It is how JSONP works

Comment: the injection is taking place by a different js file where I have defined the function callback in the similar fashion but it never gets triggered.

Comment: Is the function callback defined at a global level or is it a block level function in the external js file?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to access the values passed in the `calback()` call. Did you define the function? How? Where?

Comment: I was just able to perform it. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieved this using following code block

```
const src = function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
const injectFunc = () => {
    window.callback = src;
};
const injectScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = 'http://example.com/external.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};
```

call the function after init of app.js in following manner:

```
init () {
injectFunc();
injectScript();
}
```

In this way you will get the values in the data variable of callback which can be used in further in application if needed.

Comment: Don't make it that complicated, and especially don't rely on stringification of functions (in `script.text = src`). Why not simply do  `window.callback = src`?